# How can I make an image as big as possible, keeping the original aspect ratio and not cutting parts of the image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Th main question is in the title, but here is the issues I am having getting it working:

I have an image that I am trying to size to a page depending on the size of the window. I want to keep the original aspect ratio of the image which may be wider or taller. I figured out a way to get the aspect ratio, but is there a way to figure out how much space I have to make it both in width and height based on the other items in the screen?

From there I can figure out how to resize accordingly.

I don't want to base it on the size of the window because there might be other items there. I am also using ionic2/angular2, but I don't really think that plays a role in this issue.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Also do you want to use css or js to solve the issue ? Add the expected output as image, that would be helpful to understand your question.

Comment: A [mcve] would help to help.

Comment: either js or css to be honest. I figured I would need to make the calculation in javascript and set the css accordingly. I was going to try to set the height and width to 100% figure out how big they were and then try to make the calculation based on that and reset the height and width accordingly, but I feel like that is much more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: I'm not really sure how an example would help, it would just be a blank page with an image on it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve this, and the solution I commonly use myself, is using the CSS [`background-size`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) property. No JS is required, just a few adjustments to your HTML and CSS.

Basically what you have to do is get rid of your `<img>` element and instead create a `<div>`. Adjust your layout to give this div the appropriate size and position, and then, via CSS, give it a [`background-image`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp). You will end up with something like this:

CSS:

```
#myImg {
    background-image: url("../resources/img/myPic.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myImg">
</div>
```

The CSS properties I have set for `#myImg` do the following:

- `background-image`: Set the path for the image
- `background-size: contain`: Use the `contain` value, which scales the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the div. This is where all the magic happens behind the scenes
- `background-repeat: no repeat`: Disable repetition of the background image. If this is not set, then the image is tiled so that the entire div is covered, which we don't want.
- `background-position: center`: Position the image in the center of the div.

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts)

Comment: This would be nice the only issue is I need it to be an image since I am using cropperjs, which runs on top of an img tag. Also I want to load the image dynamically and not be forced into whatever is in my css. In addition I think I want more backward compatibility than that.

Comment: If you're using Ionic and angular2, then why would you need more backward compatibility? Anyway, if you're getting an img tag from cropperjs, you can still create a <div> with a class that has every property except the background-image, and set the background-image dynamically inline (grab it from the src attribute on the img tag and hide the img tag). It'll work like a charm.

Comment: we're using it as a webapp not a mobile app. Cropperjs receives an image tag on instantiation it does not create one. I also instantiate it on image load which I don't think I can do if I set it as a background image.

Comment: Also the sizing of cropperjs is based on the parent div not the image div which makes using this even more complicated